# calling stored list parameter in Class in Python

Tags: python, class

while attempting to create a blackjack game for Python, I found myself trying to print my players hand, but found that calling the parameter would not call the list. eventually checking the solution led me to the answer, but that only confused me more.

```
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit


class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''  # start with an empty string
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += '\n '+card.__str__() # add each Card object's print string
        return 'The deck has:' + deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card


class Hand:

    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []  # start with an empty list as we did in the Deck class
        self.value = 0   # start with zero value
        self.aces = 0    # add an attribute to keep track of aces

    def add_card(self,card):
        self.cards.append(card)
        self.value += values[card.rank]
```

with this code, I can successfully determine the value of the players hand:

```
test_player=Hand()
test_deck=Deck()
test_player.add_card(test_deck.deal())
test_player.add_card(test_deck.deal())
test_player.value
```

however, in the same logic I CANNOT determine the value of the list for self.cards, as the below prompts an error:

```
test_player.cards
#or
print(test_player.cards)
```

to make matters worse, the below function was provided in my solutions guide for this:

```
def show(player): 
    print("\nPlayer's Hand:", *player.cards, sep='\n ')

show(test_player)
```

I am hoping someone can clarify the below:

1) I do not understand what the asterisk in `*player.cards` is doing, but this function will not work without it

2) considering this function is just taking in `test_player` then running it to the Hand Class, is this not the same thing as test_player.cards? (which does not work?)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Deck:
     suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
     ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 
     'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
     values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []  # start with an empty list
        for suit in self.suits:
            for rank in self.ranks:
                self.deck.append(Card(suit,rank))

    def __str__(self):
        deck_comp = ''  # start with an empty string
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_comp += '\n '+card.__str__() # add each Card object's print string
        return 'The deck has:' + deck_comp

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.deck)

    def deal(self):
        single_card = self.deck.pop()
        return single_card
```

The problem was that the cards are not called in the class, a way to works with
this dict is in the class, if yo define that as constant, before you called with
self method, form example, self.suits calls the suits object.
Prove with this